# How to update view in a method in called from another class?

Tags: android, methods, view, nullpointerexception, android-context

In class A a have a method that updates a view.

First I called Class b to download some data, once the data is recieved I call the method in class A.

When the view is updated (when the method is called from class b) the view is throws NPE.

However if the view is updated (when called from its native class (class A)) it works perfectly.

Class A is an activity.

In some cases it reported there is some sort of context problem.

I have tried implementing an interface however even that threw an NPE

How can I fix this problem?

```
public class A extends activity {
   public() {
   }
   B b = new B();
   b.doSomething();

   public void myMethod(String string) {
     textView.setText(string)
   }
}

public class B {
  public void doSomething() {
     String data = getData;
     A a = new A();
     a.myMethod(data)
  }
}
```

Comment: Is class A an `Activity`?  Show your code.

Comment: @codebod yes it is and activty

Answer (score 0):

You should not call `new A()`. This will not invoke a new Activity with the application lifecycle, and will not provide you a reference to the original Activity that contains the `View` you are trying to update.

I would recommend `A` should implement a simple interface `YourInterface` that contains a `void callbackMethod(String data);`.

Pass your object `A` (as `this`) into `B`, such as on `doSomething(this)`, changing the signature of `doSomething` to `doSomething(YourInterface callback)`.

In `B` you may then call `callback.callbackMethod(data)`, processing `data` within your Activity `A`.

Comment: Alright thanks, I will try it when I run into the problem again. For now I am using Broadcast Receiver to communicate between classes.

Comment: The reason is that sometimes you might want to call a service from one class and update a second class once the data has been received. In that case you cannot pass the same callback.

Comment: Fair enough, but that's quite a different situation from the original question. If my answer has resolved your original question, grateful if you would accept the answer.

Comment: I realise it is different, my point is just that using an interface limits you in that regard.

Comment: I will test your answer again in the near future and let you know thanks.

Comment: I will be honest, but code is usually a lot easier to interpret